# How to get rid of Steam Coupons?

Tags: steam

My Steam inventory starts getting cluttered with coupons that will remain valid for way too long time and I'm absolutely not interested in using them or finding someone else to give them to. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Hm, I guess one _can_ consider it a dupe despite the lack of mentioning those annoying coupons anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Within Steam inventory, *some* items allow you to permanently delete them by simply clicking a button while the item is selected:

[image: Permanently delete gift...]

So far I've only seen this option for gifts.

The only way to get rid of items, which do not allow this, is to sell or give them to someone else.

Comment: As you state, this unfortunately only applies to gifts, while coupons are exempt :(

Comment: @Zommuter That is true :(